# AHK if statement ignoring conditions

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a message box for the start of a shift and perform actions based on the Yes/No options selected.

Problem is, the `if` statement fires the Yes condition regardless whether I select Yes or No.

```
MsgBox, 4, Shift start check, Are you just starting your shift? Clicking Yes will open applications/URLs for shift start.

if (MsgBox = Yes){
    Run http://wiki/ 
    Run Outlook
}
else {
    Run www.google.ca
}
```

Edit: When trying to use IfMsgBox, the following error is received:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IfMsgBox`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/IfMsgBox.htm) instead:

```
IfMsgBox, Yes
{
    Run http://wiki/
    Run Outlook
}
else
{
    Run www.google.ca
}
```

Comment: When trying the above code, I get an error saying "Parameter #1 invalid"

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe Check my edit: the syntax error may have been due to invalid block syntax. I have confirmed the above is now working as intended in my environment.